# RestTemplate call from within a spring-cloud-gateway filter hangs

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a very simple spring-cloud-gateway with a filter (which extends `AbstractGatewayFilterFactory`).

Inside the filter, I am making a REST API call using Spring's `RestTemplate`. The rest call works once, but every subsequent call from the filter just hangs and the response is never returned to the client.
I enabled logging to trace, but there wasn't anything in the logs when the REST call hangs.

I understand from one of comment  [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1229#issuecomment-518744178) by @spencergibb that anything blocking main thread of SCG is fundamentally broken. But I need this API call to be indeed blocking before I forward the request to down-stream service.

Below is my implementation (trimmed-off) of the filter:

```
@Component
public class ApiRequestHeaderFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ApiRequestHeaderFilter.Config> {

    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public ApiRequestHeaderFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            String someHeaderValue = Objects.requireNonNull(request.getHeaders().get("SOME_HEADER")).get(0);
            callRestApi();

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    private void callRestApi() {

        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = .... //build the API URL

        final ResponseEntity<List<MyCustomObject>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyCustomObject>>() {
        });

        ....  //process the response
        ....  
    }

    static class Config {
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure out the issue ? appreciate your response

Comment: @SurendraPoranki I don't remember what the issue was, but we have it working now.

Comment: I am trying to call an external service from the gatewayfilter get an error something like this block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http

Comment: @SurendraPoranki Please open a new question with more details.

Comment: We resolved the issue thanks for the response.

Comment: Any clue on how to solve this issue? Any suggestions will help

Comment: Guys any solution that you can recommend? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not read(log by reading) the request body before making a call with restTemplate. spring cloud gateway needs to record the contents of the request body, but the request body can only be read once. If the request body is not encapsulated after reading, the latter service will not be able to read the body data. [follow this](https://codar.club/blogs/spring-cloud-gateway-reads-request-body-data.html)

Comment: I am not reading the request body in filter. It is only the headers that I am reading.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the recommended way of calling another service from a `GatewayFilter` is request chaining.

For example in order to call google for every filtered request:

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> WebClient.create("https://www.google.com")
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                return exchange;
            })
            .flatMap(chain::filter);
}
```

In this example `WebClient` is used, which is a non-blocking client unlike `RestTemplate`.

`bodyToMono` method produces `Mono` that could be mapped to `exchange` after required actions in order to proceed with filtering.

For more information please see [this great baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-custom-gateway-filters#3-chaining-requests-to-other-services).